# How to insert an image in my post on Hugo?

Tags: html, css, go, hugo

Here is my repository on my Hugo blog:

[image]

I'd like to insert an image to a post with the following text:

```
![Scenario 1: Across columns](content/post/image/across_column.png)
```

However, it does not come out and it gives an error of 404 - Page not found.

What am I making wrong here?

Answer (score 37):

You have a typo in the image link. You have an `images` directory, but reference "content/post/image/..." without the "s". That won't fix it for you though.

There are a few ways to link images.

**Option 1**. Put all of your images in the `static/` directory. Then reference the image file with a leading slash, e.g.:

`![Scenario 1: Across columns](/across_column.png)`

**Option 2**. Use sub-directories to hold the markdown file and any related resources.

1. create a directory `post/creating-a-new-theme`
2. move your existing markdown file into that directory, and rename it to `index.md`
3. create a subdirectory `post/creating-a-new-theme/images` and move your images in there
4. reference the image as `![Image alt](images/my-image.jpg)`

More info on option 2: https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/1240#issuecomment-753077529

**More options**

There are more sophisticated ways to reference images using the frontmatter, as well: https://gohugo.io/content-management/page-resources/

Comment: I stumbled across this answer in the hopes that there would be a better explanation of the more sophisticated options - because that documentation is somewhat lacking :(

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

Put your images in the static directory, just like below, use it in markdown like `![targets](/images/my_post_folder/my_image.png)` or `![targets](/images/my_image2.jpg)` if you don't want to build a post folder

---

If you search the hugo documentation, you can find [Image Processing | Hugo](https://gohugo.io/content-management/image-processing/#page-resources)

But! That's no a markdown way to insert an image. If you don't miss the **Getting Stated**, you will find the **static** Directory, which says can store images, that's it!

```
[static](https://gohugo.io/content-management/static-files/)

Stores all the static content: **images**, CSS, JavaScript, etc. When Hugo builds your site, all assets inside your static directory are copied over as-is. A good example of using the static folder is for verifying site ownership on Google Search Console, where you want Hugo to copy over a complete HTML file without modifying its content.
```

**How to use it**

Put your images in the static directory, just like below, use it in markdown like `![targets](/images/my_post_folder/my_image.png)` or `![targets](/images/my_image2.jpg)` if you don't want to build a post folder

```
static
└── images
    ├── my_post_folder
    │   ├── my_image.png
    └── my_image2.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Images support is provided through [Hugo Images Module](https://hugomods.com/en/docs/images/). In my website I have for example in [config.toml](https://gitlab.com/c2platform/website/-/blob/master/config.toml)

```ini
[module]
  [[module.imports]]
    path = 'github.com/hugomods/images'
    disable = false
```

My images are stored in `assets/docs/` so this becomes a global image resource that I can than add to a post or page with

```markdown
![Resize](/images/docs/whatever.png?width=200px)
```